# Is playwright suitable for salesforce testing

Tags: automated-tests, salesforce

I am currently doing a PoC analysis to find out whether the Playwright or WebDriverIO frameworks are well suited for testing Salesforce products. Do you already have experience with the frameworks mentioned above? Thanks in advance. At the beginning of the project we decided to use Selenium as a testing framework, but then it turned out that Selenium is unfortunately not well suited

Answer (score 0):

Just POC experience with all but I would consider using [utam](https://utam.dev/) and going with the [salesforce page objects](https://www.npmjs.com/package/salesforce-pageobjects), if you do use utam I believe you need to use selenium as it will not integrate well with Playwright.